# Is it possible to access Firebase data before creating a new user? (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Before creating my new user, I would like to check Firebase to see if the username already exists in the database. I would like to do this right after the user has finished editing the username textfield (the rest of my form will not be complete). I've attempted to access the Firebase DB, but I get the warning "Listener at /Users failed: permission_denied". From what I understand, in order to read/write to/from the Firebase DB the user must be authenticated, and obviously a user signing up isn't authenticated before they've signed up. Is there any way to access the database before running the `createUserWithEmail:password:completion:` method?

Comment: The bigger question; is the email address that's used when creating a Firebase account the same as a *user name*? If yes, then Firebase will automatically tell you if that user name already exists when you try to create the user. If no, why not?

Comment: I would prefer to check the username/email uniqueness immediately after the user finishes editing the username/email textfield, as opposed to the user having to complete the entire form, submitting it and then telling them to select a new username/email (assuming it's a duplicate). However, for simplicity I may just go with this route. Thanks @Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, let me say up front that I do **NOT** recommend you do this for your use case. But in general, you can allow unauthenticated users to access parts of the database by setting your security rules for that path to true:

```
{
   "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
    }
}
```

You would *not* want to do something like this because you don't want to give the public access to everyone's usernames.

Instead, I'd recommend using Cloud Functions for Firebase. You can create a Cloud Function that is triggered when a user chooses a username, perhaps by creating a temporary path in the database and using a database trigger. Now if you're not familiar with Cloud Functions or Node.js, there will be a lot of new information to learn up front, but you will discover that there are many use cases for Functions, so it's worth learning.

Here are some resources to check out:

[Get Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ)

[Cloud Functions Database Triggers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0)

[Cloud Functions Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, @JenPerson! I intended including 'safe' in the question, so I'll be going with your second suggestion.